# Raspberry Hardware simulator to practice on

Tags: gpio

I don't own a raspberry (it's in the mail) and would like to practice coding and interacting with the IO ports to turn on LED lights.

Is there an gui hardware simulator someone can point me too?  I've seen this for Arduinos where you can practice on a board through a gui.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such a graphical hardware emulator. 
To emulate software running on the Raspberry Pi, you can use [Qemu](http://qemu-project.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you'd emulate the GPIO, but, setting up Raspbian under an emulator is completely possible, and explained [here (Raspberry Pi Emulation Using `qemu-user-static`)](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi/qemu-user-static. [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) is used for the actual hardware emulation.